# Algorithm for an extended version of string matching

Tags: algorithm, string-matching

I recently studied about string matching, and was inspired to think of a similar problem. Let *p* be a string of *m* characters and *t* be a text of *n* characters. Now the problem is to find out if *p* occurs in *t* in the following way: there exists an *i* in the range [0, *n*-1] such that:

*p*[ *j* ] = *t* [ *i* + *j* ] for *j* = 0, 1, ... ,*m* - 1,

where *i* + *j* is computed modulo *n*. As an example, in normal string matching, ABCD would not occur in CDEFAB, but you can see that in the above-defined problem, ABCD would occur in CDEFAB, *i* = 4 in this case.

Is there any linear-time algorithm to determine if a pattern *p* occurs in *t*? And has this problem been treated before?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can still apply the linear time [KMP algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) to solve it. Just add m-1 characters t[0], t[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm),...,t[m-2] to the end of the text t. Ofcourse you only need to do this if you still have a candidate substring left in your table after the text t ends.

If test string is BCDEA
AXYZBCDE shall become AXYZBCDEAXYZ

Answer (score 0):

Just double t and make an ordinary lookup for p?

So you would look up ABCD in CDEFABCDEFAB and would get the right i. That can be made in linear time.